# C++ Libraries in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl, libraries

I was wondering if we can use c++ libraries to write programs in OpenCL. Can we use the boost library or STL or any other c++ library to write code in OpenCL  OpenCL devices?? Will it work on OpenCL devices? Any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I just pictured graphics cards running heavily-nested templated Boost code. Oh boy.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use any C++ libraries in OpenCL C. OpenCL C is based on C99 and has lots of additional restrictions. OpenCL does not support recursion, multi-dimensional arrays, dynamic memory allocation and many more C99/C++ features. See [this list](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/restrictions.html).

Comment: I am taking about OpenCL C++ which was added in OpenCL 2.1 specification. According to Khronos, OpenCL C++ inherits many features of C++.  OpenCL C++ is based on C++14 and supports many useful features, including:
• Classes and basic object-oriented programming3
• Templates, type traits, and template metaprogramming
• Operator overloading
• Function overloading
• Lambdas
• Namespaces